# How do I get audio to play on multiple files using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few files where I want to add audio for some buttons. I was able to add audio to one of my files by using this code:

**Javascript File:**

```
function play(player){
    var hana = document.getElementById(player);
    hana.play();
}

 function play(player){
     var dul = document.getElementById(player);
     dul.play();
}        

function play(player){
    var set = document.getElementById(player);
    set.play();
}
```

...

**Html File:**

```
            <li><input type="button" class="ui-header 
            button"value="One"onclick="play('hana')">
              <audio id="hana" src="audio/hana.wav"></audio><div 
              id="vocab">Ha-na<br  /><br  />하나</div></li>

            <li><input type="button" class="ui-header button" value="Two" onclick="play('dul')">
              <audio id="dul" src="audio/dul.wav"></audio><div id="vocab">Dul<br  /><br  />둘</div></li>

            <li><input type="button" class="ui-header button" value="Three" onclick="play('set')">
              <audio id="set" src="audio/set.wav"></audio><div id="vocab">Set<br  /><br  />셋</div></li>
```

However, when I tried using the same code on a separate page of the site, the sounds would no longer play. I can't figure out why it's only working for one of my files but not the rest.

For the sounds on the second page I added the same code with different variables to the javascript file:

```
    function play(player){
    var annyeong = document.getElementById(player);
    annyeong.play();
          }
```

And the following code is on a seperate html file:

```
<li><input type="button" class="ui-header button" value="Hello" onclick="play('annyeong')">
        <audio id="annyeong" src="audio/annyeong.wav"></audio><div id="vocab">Ann-yeong-ha-se-yo<br  /><br  />안녕하세요</div></li>
```

Comment: What do you mean, another file. If you load it with `AJAX` you have to get the `element` again. In the `success` `function`.

Comment: I mean another page on my site. I am able to get the audio to work for the buttons on one of the pages but it does not work for the rest of the pages when using the same method in the code above. Sorry if I am using the wrong terms, I am pretty new to coding.

Comment: OK. Do you load the other pages with refreshing of the site. Or asynchronously with `AJAX`? Want to know.

Comment: By refreshing the site.

Comment: Can you show the `code` of the second page, please?

Comment: I will add the code to my original post post so you can see it better

Comment: @AjAX. I think I figured it out! I had all the function names the same. Once I gave them all different names everything seemed to work properly. Thanks for your help!